# How can I validate unique form elements in jinja2/pyramid/sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, jinja2

Is there was a easy way to validate unique elements in a user entered form? I found ways to do it in php(lookup values after user enters it in table) but not sure how to do it using jinja2

For example, say a user is signing up and I require all email addresses to be unique, how can I let them know its not unique before they submit the results(like this: https://github.com/signup/free if you are already a member if you enter your email it'll tell you it exists as soon as you go to the next line. I've seen many sites do this)? Right now I can catch the errors but it refreshes the page and gives them an error and I'd like to let them know their form will fail before they hit submit.   In this example, I'm checking for something that does not exist but in some other examples I'll want to check if something in the database exists.

I understand I'll need to query my database but I'm unsure how to do it from the template itself or if there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using javascript or Jquery, you could do a message system, passing it to the renderer through a dict. For example:

```
message = ''
if 'form.submitted' in request.params:#form.submitted being the name of the submit of the form
    #check if email exists
    if exists:
         message = 'email already registered'
    else:
         message = 'success'
return dict(message = message)
```

Just a way of doing it without the JS

Comment: Thanks Wiz...good to know. My current approach is to make email a primary key and then catch `except IntegrityError:` errors but I was thinking maybe there was a way to warn the users in advance since its super annoying to submit a form only to find out it failed.

Comment: You can actually save all the values of the forms, and give the renderer a dict of all of them, allowing the parts of the form that were filled in correctly to be automatically filled in when you get the response.

Comment: didn't think of that, I'll apply that to my existing code but I still wanted to give that real time feedback(because it would apply to many other areas of my site)..but thanks for that..I did wonder why my forms kept returning blank and how others kept the values. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do an **XMLHttpRequest** ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest ) with **Javascript** to **POST** the input box's text (even easier if you use **jQuery**, as in the upcoming example) and do a DB query server-side to see if the email (input box text) is unique. Accordingly, you would return a response from this view, where `xhr=True` in the `@view_config()` decorator for non-IE browsers and `request.response.content_type='text/html'` is set for IE browsers. For example:

```
@view_config(permission='view', route_name='check_email', renderer='json') ##for IE browsers
@view_config(permission='view', route_name='check_email', renderer='json', xhr=True) ##for non-IE
def check_email(request):
    email= request.POST['email']

    dbquery = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.email==email).first()

    ## if the email exists in the DB
    if dbquery:
        msg = 'used'
    ## else if the email is available
    else:
        msg = 'available'

    if request.is_xhr:
        return {'msg':msg}
    else: # for IE browser
        request.response.content_type = 'text/html'
        return Response(json.dumps({'msg':msg}))
```

You can do a POST easily (client-side) by using a library such as jQuery to take care of the XMLHttpRequest. After including the jQuery library in your template, as well as the .js file with you script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{request.static_url('tutorial:static/myscript.js')}}"></script>
```

And then in **myscript.js** do:

```
$(function() {
  $('#email').on('blur', postEmail)
})

// this function POSTs the entered email
function postEmail() {
  var email = $(this).val()
  $.post('/check_email', email, callback)
}

// this function is used to do something with the response returned from your view
function callback(data) {
  if (data['msg'] === 'used') {
    alert('used')
  }
  else if (data['msg'] === 'available') {
    alert('available')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Raj..I completely understand your python code but I'm very new to Java Script/Jquery..and I put your code into my form(and created your myscript.js and added jquery.js)..I don't get any errors but I don't get anything new.  Do I wrap the script tags into my `input` tags in the form? or how do I integrate it into my form?

Comment: Hmmm, can you paste your current code into a pastebin of some sort (http://paste.ofcode.org for example) so I can better understand what you have going on?

Comment: Thanks so much for offering to take a look. My pyramid code is a simple form that takes the data. I created a view and route based on your `check_username` code, and here's my jinja2 code: http://paste.ofcode.org/35cnVY7vMXABuVJM3nSVWa9

Comment: You've got a couple issues with your html (jinja2) code. For one, you repeated `<label for="lastname">` three times over. And secondly, you should separate your css <style> from your html, by placing them in a .css file.

Comment: I have updated the explanation above to make it more specific to your pastebin code.

Comment: Thanks Raj I fixed the jinja2 code and tried your updated code but same effect..nothing seems to happen. Is there something I need to add to jinja code to display and trigger the search? Do I wrap the input tags in anything or {% if msg %} ...to display the message?

Comment: I'm sorry for being a pain, I've been reading and in examples I've seen there are generating the form using jquery http://livevalidation.com/examples  but I'm confused how to wrap the form so it checks the database and also since I'm not using the standard `<input..` tag, will pyramid pick it up? As you can see I am totally new to combining jqeury/jinja2/pyramid..

Comment: @Lostsoul, are you sure the javascript file is being used? 
Make
$(function() {
  $('#email').on('blur', postEmail)
})
into:
$(function() {
  alert("Yes, it's working");
  $('#email').on('blur', postEmail)
})